# Asynchronous Actionmailer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've noticed some of my actions (on a development environment) take a little while to load up as an email they require an email notification (through Google's servers).  Do I need to implement asynchronous handling of emails like - http://upstream-berlin.com/2008/05/19/new-rails-plugin-for-making-actionmailer-asynchronous/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Offloading potentially long-running tasks such as sending emails in to the background is a good idea to improve the responsiveness of your application, albeit by sacrificing the simplicity of your application a little.

One popular way to do this (which I have used with great success) is using [Delayed Job](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).  The README file contains examples of how simple it is to send email in the background -- basically you just use the `send_later` method.

Here's a link to another good tutorial:

http://railstips.org/2008/11/19/delayed-gratification-with-rails

Answer (score 1):

I've just released a gem, Mailhopper, that queues email in your database for asynchronous sending plus optional archiving. A second gem, DelayedMailhopper, queues and sends these emails using DelayedJob.

I developed this approach to be more robust than DelayedJob alone, as explained here:

http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2011/09/07/tame-rails-email-dragons-with-mailhopper/

Comment: We're using mailhopper in production without a problem. You may want to check that your DelayedJob queue is running, and verify the sent status of your emails. You could also try sending messages directly with smtp to ensure your smtp settings are working. Feel free to file an issue on github if you still have problems.

Comment: it was me being stupid, I should run delayed job worker myself (didn't know that). sorry about false alarm.

Comment: thanks, you have done a great job with mailhopper, thumbs up!